# Network traffic

Tags: monitoring

I have a task to do research on network traffic analysis in cloud systems, but I'am not really sure what exactly means network traffic. Can you please explain it bit more. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should clarify the task with the person who gave it to you? We cannot guess what this person has in mind. The sentence is too vague / broad.

Answer (score 2):

Network traffic is a very generic word , so shortly if you want to dig this field you need to understand two main things.

1. ***NETWORKING*** is ***ADDRESSING***

this address may be L2 address(mac for example) or L3 address (IPV4 for example) and this address could be source or destination.

2. ***Traffic*** is ***parameters***

this parameters could be protocols

- transition protocol *TCP* or *UDP*
- application protocol *http* or *https*
  and so on

this traffic also could be treated by quality of service (QOS)

so simply if PC_1 make traffic to PC_2 (ping for example) and you could obtain the information of 
***source mac , source IP , destination mac , destination IP , this traffic is UDP or TCP , this traffic QOS is best effort for example*** you successfully made network analyses

but lets say cloud network analyses not simply as this example it could include more information like application type and number of sessions payload of each session and so on

if you want to see demo of network analyses obtained from real data center may you access [ORION live demo](http://oriondemo.solarwinds.com/Orion/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2F)

Answer (score 1):

> Network traffic refers to the amount of data moving across a network at a given point of time. Network data is mostly encapsulated in network packets, which provide the load in the network. Network traffic is the main component for network traffic measurement, network traffic control and simulation.

This is a basic definition of network traffic.

Your question is too wide to answer without any more technical details on exactly the purpose of the analysis.

Do you need to know the type of traffic that is being transmitted, such as what protocol is being used, where the traffic flows to, ie destination or perhaps the source of the traffic?

Or are you being asked to monitor the consumption of bandwidth such as the throughput?

Answer (score 1):

It seems opinions on this vary, but FWIW here is mine.

Network traffic is simply the data sent between devices on a network.

Therefor, traffic analysis can mean a lot of things. Compare it with real-life road traffic. Traffic analysis there could mean to measure average speed or top speed, distance between vehicles, size/color/type of cars/buses/trucks, amount of people inside the vehicles, count how many vehicles are passing by per minute (or how many 20th century white convertibles pass) etc. etc.

Similarly you can analyse the traffic on a network to check how many bytes are transmitted, how much (average) delay there is, how much of the traffic is using a certain protocol (IPv4 vs IPv6, TCP vs UDP vs other, etc.) and lots, lots more.

Answer (score 1):

Network traffic analysis is the process of recording, reviewing and analyzing network traffic for the purpose of performance, security and/or general network operations and management.

It is the process of using manual and automated techniques to review granular-level detail and statistics within network traffic.

[please refer to this page](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/29976/network-traffic-analysis)